# How to add row in DataGridView programmatically

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, addition, rows

Here I've tried this code. But, my problem now is that, it doesn't display any data.

**Here is my code**

```
try
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    con.Open();

    dt.Load(new MySqlCommand("SELECT variant_name FROM tblVariant_Product WHERE product_name='" + cboProduct.Text + "'", con).ExecuteReader());

    DataColumn col = dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Quantity", typeof(Int32));
    col.AllowDBNull = false;

    DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
    row["variant_name"] = "TOTAL";
    row["quantity"] = 0;
    dt.Rows.Add(row);

    dataGridView2.DataSource = dt;
    con.Close();
}
catch (Exception)
{
}
```

Comment: dataGridView2.DataBind() ?

Comment: @DevProve after typing the datagridview2 and the period the databind does not show in the intellisense instead it shows DataBindings and DataBindingComplete.

Comment: @DevProve is there another way to add a new row?

Comment: opss sorry yours is window app

Answer (score 3):

Write:

```
dt.AcceptChanges();
```

after:

```
dt.Rows.Add(row);
```

Comment: The same, and I double check in my database table `tblVariant_Product` that it has data but when I run the program it doesn't display that data. Why is that?

Comment: Please check dt in QuickWatch at this  dt.Load(new MySqlCommand("SELECT variant_name FROM tblVariant_Product WHERE product_name='" + cboProduct.Text + "'", con).ExecuteReader()); at debug time is datatable(dt) contains data at this point?

Comment: Sorry I'm a beginner in using visual studio, so how would I know that dt contains data?

Comment: add debug point using F9 key at this line and run the application

Comment: Okay I'm already running the application and the line is highlighted with the cursor blinking and after that?

Comment: Okay what I'm seeing now is a new form that has two buttons `Reevaluate` and `Add Watch`, with Expression dt. What's the next step?

Comment: Press F10 until you reach the  DataColumn col = dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Quantity", typeof(Int32)); line

Comment: new MySqlCommand("SELECT variant_name FROM tblVariant_Product WHERE product_name='" + cboProduct.Text + "'", con).ExecuteReader();
i think u didn't get any data

Comment: Is there any data in Quickwatch?

Comment: @DevProve. I think so because previously when I don't have this line `DataColumn col = dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Quantity", typeof(Int32));
            col.AllowDBNull = false;`. It displays data on the datagridview.

Comment: @DevProve Thank you I've removed the line `col.AllowDBNull = false;` and now it's working. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To add column:

```
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ColumnName",Type.GetType("System.String")));
```

and its better to remove the it first:

```
dataGridView2.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: No it has two columns `variant_name` and `Quantity`, whereas the Quantity is the one that I've added in datagridview2 property.

Comment: Okay I get it...I think I know the error. So now I have a question if you don't mind, what is the syntax for adding a column in datatable?

Comment: It doesn't display any data, anyway I updated my question already.

Comment: Check your cboProduct.Text it maybe null

Comment: I don't think so because it's functioning previously.

Comment: DataColumn col = dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Quantity", typeof(Int32));
row["quantity"] = 0;
the "Q"

Answer (score 0):

```
try{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    con.Open();

    dt.Load(new MySqlCommand("SELECT variant_name FROM tblVariant_Product WHERE product_name='" + cboProduct.Text + "'", con).ExecuteReader());

    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Quantity", typeof(Int32));

    DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
    row["variant_name"] = "TOTAL";
    row["quantity"] = 0;
    dt.Rows.Add(row);

    dataGridView2.DataSource = dt;
    con.Close();
 }
 catch (Exception)
 {
 }
```